# select columns from a table within a cursor

Tags: sql-server

For each item (actually a value, "ut" in the code) selected from the table #pub, I want to create some tables based on this "ut" value and then, if some criteria are satisfied, I will print this "ut". But there are some errors in my SQL Server code shown below.

```
select ut
into #pub
from wosclassification1813..clustering
where cluster_id1 = 145

DECLARE @temp_ut NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @citation_count INT;
DECLARE @dccp_count INT;
DECLARE @temp_string_1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @temp_string_2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @i INT;
SET @i = 1;
DECLARE @j INT;
SET @j = 0;
DECLARE @n INT;
SET @n = (select count(*) from #pub);

Declare Cur Cursor For select ut from #pub
Open Cur
Fetch next From Cur Into @temp_ut    
WHILE @j < @n
Begin
    SET @temp_string_1 = (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @i))
    EXEC('select s_ut as ut into @temp_string_1 from woskb.dbo.cwts_pairs where c_ut = @temp_ut')
    SET @temp_string_2 = (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @i))
    EXEC('select a.c_ut as c_ut, a.s_ut as s_ut into temp_string_2 from woskb.dbo.cwts_pairs as a join @temp_string_1 as b on a.c_ut = b.ut join @temp_string_1 as c on a.s_ut = c.ut')
    SET @dccp_count = (select count(*) from #dccp)
    SET @citation_count = (select count(*) from #citing_pub)
    SET @i = @i + 1
    SET @j = @j + 1
    if @dccp_count = @citation_count*(@citation_count-1)/2
        print @temp_ut
    Fetch Next From Cur Into @temp_ut
End   
Close Cur   
Deallocate Cur
```

Comment: hi @gary , please add exception to your post  .

Comment: what is actually failing? and also, why dynamic sql? more than likely the variable in your string is not in scope, and will not work properly. I'd suggest reading this article on the pitfalls of dynamic sql. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html